# How to remove caret from a <select> element in bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I know there are plenty of answers to this question already, but none of them work now. Probably due to Bootstrap update.

Here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/N0ir/Yh33b/

Who can figure this out?

```
<select>
    <option value="1">Misha, davai po novoi</option>
</select>


.caret {
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change or alter the caret using css as the select element is generated by the browser by default (that's why they look different from browser to browser). You need to use js/css to get the change you want as well as keep it browser compatible. Here is a link to a nice one for Bootstrap users:

http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/3/